# List nodes in Ada

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, nodes, ada

So I'm writing a linked list in Ada - a pretty simple task. In the list.ads file, I declare a list node like so:

```
type Node;
type Node_Ptr is access Node;

type Node is record
  Data: Integer;
  Next: Node_Ptr;
end record;
```

In the adb file, I declare the head node as a sentinel:

```
Head: Node_Ptr := new Node_Ptr'(null, null);
```

From what I've read and seen, this should work. However, when I try to compile, it tells me that "expected type Node declared in list.ads", even though I already defined the type. Weirdly enough, it tells me that Node_Ptr is appropriately defined, but Node is not. What gives?

Comment: `:= new Node'(0,null);` ... New creates a new *object* (not ptr), and `null` isn't a valid integer

Comment: You could also say `new Node'(Data => 0, Next => null)`, using named notation for the fields.

Answer (score 0):

The line with the error is

```
   Head: Node_Ptr := new Node_Ptr'(null, null);
```

The error message that GNAT GPL 2014 gives is

```
list.adb:2:34: expected type "Node" defined at list.ads:5
list.adb:2:34: found type "Node_Ptr" defined at list.ads:3
```

which is pointing at the `’` after the last character of `Node_Ptr`; the compiler has seen `Head : Node_Ptr := new` and is expecting the type `Node`.

In contrast, GCC 4.9.1 says

```
list.adb:2:35: expected type "Node_Ptr" defined at list.ads:3
list.adb:2:35: found a composite type
```

pointing at the opening paren of `(null, null)`; it has seen the `Node_Ptr’` and parsed the `(null, null)` sufficiently to see that it’s a composite type and can’t possibly be a value compatible with `Node_Ptr`.

As has already been said, the correct way of allocating a value is

```
FP : Foo_Ptr := new {value of type Foo};
```

or in your case

```
Head : Node_Ptr := new Node'(null, null);
```

.. but that fails on both compilers with

```
list.adb:2:33: expected type "Standard.Integer"
list.adb:2:33: found an access type
```

pointing at the first `null`.

I think you can probably fix it from there.